# For $L $ a linear functional, show that $\{x: Lx=0 \} $ is a closed subset.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, continuity, linear-transformations

Let $L $ be continuous linear functional from a vector space $H $.

Show that the set $$M=\{x: Lx=0 \} $$ is a closed subspace of $H$, where $H $ is any vector space. I can show that $M $ is a subspace, but I need help with the showing that the set is closed.

There is a hint that I should use the continuity of $L $.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that $M=L^{-1}(0)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function $f: X\to Y$ is continuous if and only if it inverts closed sets, i.e., $f^{-1}[F]$ is a closed subset of $X$ whenever $F$ is a closed subset of $Y$.

But in your case $\{0\}$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb R$ (or $\mathbb C$) and hence so is
$$
L^{-1}(\{0\})=\{x:Lx=0\}.
$$

Note. In the case of linear functionals on normed spaces (even topological vector spaces) the converse is also true: If  $\{x:Lx=0\}$ is closed, then $L$ is bounded.

Comment: Deleted mine, this is more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

$M=X\setminus L^{-1}[(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)$ Now $L$ is continuous hence $L^{-1}[(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)$ is open. So M is closed.